# Priority Queue - Consecutive Groups of Integers

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am working on this question: 
Divide a list of numbers into group of consecutive numbers but their original order should be preserved?
 e.g.
 input: 8,2,4,7,1,0,3,6
 output: 2,4,1,0,3 and 8,7,6

I implemented a solution, simply put:

1. Store the original array into a map with the key being the input elements and the value being their indices in the original array.
2. sort the input array
3. go through the sorted array and add each element in a priorityqueue when the numbers are consecutive.

But there're some bugs with the `PriorityQueue`. For example, if the input is `{2,4,3}`, the `PriorityQueue` will end up being `{2,3,4}`. I tried to debug it, and what I found is that my implementation works fine with two numbers, but when I added the 3rd number, it only compares itself with the head of the queue, so the 3 (original index 2) was never compared with 4 (original index 1). So it seems that the new Pair added to this queue is not compared against every other element. But this shouldn't happen, so I am not really sure what the problem is, can someone please help me take a look at my code?

```
public class ConsecutiveGroupsofIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> input = Lists.newArrayList(2,4,3);

        List<PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> groups = findGroups(input);

        for(PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> group : groups){
            for(Pair<Integer, Integer> pair : group){
                System.out.print(pair.getKey() + ",");
            }
            System.out.println("============");
        }

    }

    public static List<PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> findGroups(List<Integer> input){

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
            map.put(input.get(i), i);
        }

        Collections.sort(input);
        List<PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        PairComparator comparator = new PairComparator();
        PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> group = new PriorityQueue<>(input.size(),comparator);
        int first = input.get(0);
        group.add(new ImmutablePair<>(first, map.get(first)));
        for(int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++){
            int num = input.get(i);
            int index = map.get(num);

            if(input.get(i) - input.get(i-1) > 1){
                groups.add(group);
                group = new PriorityQueue<>(input.size(),comparator);
            }
            group.add(new ImmutablePair<>(num, index));

            if(i == input.size()-1){
                groups.add(group);
            }

        }

        return groups;
    }

    public static class PairComparator implements Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) {
            return o1.getRight() - o2.getRight();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your grouping criteria?

Comment: @I.K. Each group only contains consecutive numbers, so my grouping criteria is input.get(i) - input.get(i-1) <= 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct except for the way you are printing. :-)

When you iterate over the priority queue, do not expect it to give you elements in the order you expect. If you need the items in order, you should actually be using `.peek(..)` or `.poll(..)` methods instead.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of
>   the Collection and Iterator interfaces. **The Iterator provided in
>   method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the
>   priority queue in any particular order.** If you need ordered traversal,
>   consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

---

For traversal, you should consider sorting manually after converting to a list. For a one time use, you should instead do:

```
while (!group.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(group.poll().getKey() + ",");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it does print in the correct order now. What I don't understand is that when i was debugging it, the order shows in the debugger was the wrong order (same order when i tried to print out in my original code), but when i do poll.getkey(), the order is fixed. so my question is why is that order shown in the debugger different than the actual order (poll())? thanks

Comment: That's because even your debugger is doing the same thing as you did to display the content of the priority queue instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original order, you need to make that a minor key of the Comparator.

Comment: would you please explain what'd mean by a "minor key of the comparator"? I thought the way i implemented the comparator should have provided enough info for ordering. or did you mean something like linkedhashmap?